# Change password of a user in a REST API

Tags: rest, api

I'm developing a small REST API. I have a user resource with this fields in my database:

```
{
  email: String,
  password: String,
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  age: Number,
  location: String
}
```

When I query a specific user resource I'm returning all the fields except the `password` field for security reasons.

Now I want to make a form in the client side so a user can update his personal information and his password. The change password form will have two inputs: `old_password` and `new_password`.

Here comes my doubt. I want to have a PUT method so I can send all the fields and update the user. But the `old_password` and `new_password` will rarely be filled so they cannot be send to the server every time the user makes a PUT request.

- Is it ok to send that two fields sometimes to a PUT method? Is it RESTful?
- Other idea is to have a PATCH method with that two fields and only update the user password. But then my PUT method is not updating the user password and it's not being correctly used right?

Which is the most RESTful approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set default values when the value doesn't exists or use a flag on the server to check if the value is present. But .., A PUT would have to deliver full object to the resource. The main reason of this, is that PUT should be idempotent. This means a request, which is repeated should evaluate to the same result on the server. If you allow partial updates, it cannot be idem-potent anymore.

Use the PATCH method which allows you to partially update a structure. It Submits a partial modification to a resource. If you only need to update one field for the resource, you may want to use the PATCH method.

Comment: But sometimes you are updating the complete resource and sometimes not. This is not RESTful right?

Comment: Ok.. So then, I need to have two methods: PUT for update the complete resource and PATCH to only change the password. This is my main idea, but in the PUT you are not sending the password thus you are not updating the complete resource. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes this is fine as long as there are no multiple entries of the same user .

Answer (score 2):

We solved this my creating a 'password' resource. A url to this resource might look like:

```
/users/x/password
```

Only `PUT` is supported. Any other request will result in a `405` error.